# .NET 6 Blazor WASM. Can't Find appsetting.json File

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In my program.cs I have

```
var config = builder.Configuration;
try
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    
}
```

I am getting the exception

```
'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/appsettings.json'.'
```

The file appsettings.json is in the root directory of the project and copy to output directory is "Copy always".

I also tried using:

```
try
{
    IConfigurationBuilder config2 = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsetting.json");

    config2.Build();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

This has the same error. Why is the file not found?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the appsettings.json goes into WWWROOT FOLDER in a Blazor WASM peoject not project root.